# Sails JS. Unable to 'create' from POST form

Tags: javascript, url, post, sails.js

I'm attempting to create a new Customer in my database using Sails. this works as you would expect when I manually enter the parameters via the URL, however when I use a POST method via a form, I get a 404 not found error, which makes little sense as when I refresh the page to the same URL, I get a new error informing me of undefined properties (which would make sense, as I haven't defined any). I have checked the Chrome console and the POST method seems to be sending the data in the correct URL formal.

**Customer Controller**

```
/**
 * CustomerController
 *
 * @description :: Server-side actions for handling incoming requests.
 * @help        :: See https://sailsjs.com/docs/concepts/actions
 */

module.exports = {

    'new': function (req, res) {
        res.view();
    }


};
```

**new.ejs (new customer creation view)**

```
<form action="/customer/create" method="POST"> 

<h2> Create customer</h2>

<input type="text" placeholder="Name" name="name" ></br/>
<input type="text" placeholder="Email" name= "email" ></br/>
<input type="text" placeholder="State" name = "state" ><br/>

<input type="submit" value="Create Customer"/>

</form>
```

**Customer.js (model)**

```
/**
 * Customer.js
 *
 * @description :: A model definition.  Represents a database table/collection/etc.
 * @docs        :: https://sailsjs.com/docs/concepts/models-and-orm/models
 */

module.exports = {

  attributes: {

    name: {
      type: 'string',
      required: true
    },

    email: {
      type:'string',
      isEmail: true
    },

    state: {
      type: 'string'
    }
  },
};
```

The full project is here; https://github.com/daneroe/Sails-Test-App

Answer (score 1):

Fixed! **

Seems in older versions of sails that if you wanted to use the 'create' method, that you had to explicitly point it to the URL and include '/create'. in current version, it doesn't seem to require this and posting directly to the '/customer' (or whichever 'model' you use) creates a new record automatically.